# Calculate 5 months before a date value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that outputs a date, and I'd like to add an additional column that represents the date 5 months prior to that date. So if the output value is 2012-06 then I want to show 2012-01.

Comment: _"and here is the format of my date "_ A `date` or `datetime` has no _format_ but a value.

Comment: So do you want 5 full months (including the current month) e.g. from June 1st at midnight -> today, the 5 previous months prior to this month (May 1st at midnight -> September 30 just before midnight), May 4, 2013 at around the current time until right now, or do you just want an additional column in the output that shows whatever date is in the first column, minus 5 months? Being vague isn't very helpful. Please show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Tim also you can't store a date or datetime as `yyyy-mm`...

Comment: i want an additional column in the output that shows whatever date is in the first column, minus 5 months

Comment: @AaronBertrand: That's why i guess that he actually stores it in a varchar column.

Comment: @Tim right, that was more for moe than for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  unnamed_date_column, 
  5_months_earlier = DATEADD(MONTH, -5, unnamed_date_column)
FROM dbo.unnamed_table;
```

If you are storing these as varchar (which you must be if they are in `yyyy-mm`, and you should stop doing that), then you can do this:

```
SELECT
  unnamed_date_column, 
  5_months_earlier = DATEADD(MONTH, -5, unnamed_date_column)
FROM 
(
  SELECT unnamed_date_column = CONVERT(DATETIME, unnamed_varchar_column + '-01')
  FROM dbo.unnamed_table
) AS x;
```

Of course, that could generate an error, because if you chose the wrong data type for this column, anybody could have entered `2013-13` or `1623-99` or `who_dat` into this column...

Answer (score 0):

```
select [column]
  from [table]
 where [datecol] between DATEADD(month, -5, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

After computing the start date of the first month (`@Start`) and the end date (`@End`) of the last month:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate SMALLDATETIME; -- Or DATE[TIME][2][OFFSET]
SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE(); -- 2013-10-05

DECLARE @Start SMALLDATETIME, @End SMALLDATETIME;

SET @Start  = DATEADD(MONTH, (DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @CurrentDate) - 4), 0);
SET @End    = DATEADD(MONTH, (DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @CurrentDate) + 1), 0);

SELECT  @Start AS [@Start], @End AS [@End];
/*
@Start     @End
---------- ----------
2013-06-01 2013-11-01
*/
```

you could filter the rows using these predicates:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE SomeDateColumn >= @Start AND SomeDateColumn < @EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
DECLARE @DT DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),@DT, 120) AS TODAY_DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),DATEADD(MM,-5,@DT), 120 ) AS BEFORE_5_MONTHS
```